# Getting undefined on try to connect mysql with node js using consign

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, node-modules, ecmascript-5

I'm using consign to make the autoload from modules on my Node JS api, in this I load all my routes, models and my database connection function, When I run the `nodemom app` the module that makes the connection is loaded but I Cannot connect to the database, he throws me this error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'db' of undefined`

Look at my tree files:

[image]

I can load the routes cuz

db.js (File that has de database configuration)

```
var mysql = require('mysql');

var connMySQL = function () {
    console.log("I've Started the connection")
    return mysql.createConnection({
        host: 'localhost',
        user: 'root',
        password: '',
        database: 'agimplant'
    });
}

module.exports = function () {
    console.log("I've loaded this function")
    return connMySQL;
}
```

Server.js

```
var express = require('express'),
    bodyparser = require('body-parser'),
    consign = require('consign'),
    app = express();

consign()
    .include('./src/routes')
    .then('./src/config/db.js')
    .then('./src/models')
    .into(app);

app.use(bodyparser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.listen(4000, function () {
    console.log("Servidor ON");
});

module.exports = app;
```

Connection Calling on Home.route.js

```
module.exports = function (app) {
    app.get('/', (req, res) => {
        console.log("Call the Connection Here")
        var connection = app.config.db();
    });
}
```

Comment: `app.config` must be undefined - where have *you* given it a value?

Comment: Make sure your database is discoverable by any computer user if using MAMP, and set the port options.

Comment: @JaromandaX, I've made it on the consign, here .then('./src/config/db.js')

Comment: @Raymond I have tried to connect to other databases and it throws the same error, i have other aplication that connects normally.

Comment: @JaromandaX Sorry, but I dont get it.. if it makes nothing, how could I give a value to the config? Thanks!

Comment: @JaromandaX He is, it is a function through the cosign library. Not smart of them.

Comment: Oh ... sorry, I see a chain of  `.then` and immediately think `Promise` ... will remove my comments

Comment: It's Ok, @JaromandaX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in the consign of the src patch, put app.src.conf for called your object.
Put src for methods access always and use console.log from debbug it's is great